# How to declare a reference to a struct with generic type in Rust?

Tags: generics, rust

I am new to rust and this is difficult to express in my words, but here is some code:

```
use super::application::Application; // this is a trait

static mut sessions: Vec<&Session</* what to put in here?*/>> = Vec::with_capacity(8);

pub struct Session<T: Application> {
    app: Box<T>,
}

pub fn create_session<T: Application>(ini_file: &str, app: T) -> Session<T> {
    let session = Session {
        app: Box::new(app),
    };
    sessions.append(session);
    session
}
```

The compiler needs the type of the generic, but really I think it should not because the size wont matter in a reference and I want this to be generic to any struct implementing Application.

How should I declare the `sessions` Vec?

I tried

`static mut sessions: Vec<&Session<T: Application>> = Vec::with_capacity(8);`

`static mut sessions: Vec<&Session> = Vec::with_capacity(8);`

`static mut sessions: Vec<&Session<dyn Application>> = Vec::with_capacity(8);` (even when I dont think dynamic dispatching is needed, maybe I am wrong.

I also tried the same with Boxing instead of reference but got the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You code has many issues so I've fixed those to produce this.

```rs
use std::sync::Mutex;

pub trait Application {}

pub trait SessionApplication: Sync {}
impl<T: Application + Sync> SessionApplication for Session<T> {}

static SESSIONS: Mutex<Vec<&dyn SessionApplication>> = Mutex::new(Vec::new());

pub struct Session<T> {
    pub app: T,
}

pub fn create_session<T>(app: T) -> &'static Session<T>
where
    T: Application + Sync,
{
    let session = Session { app };
    let session = Box::new(session);
    let session = Box::leak(session);
    SESSIONS.lock().unwrap().push(session);
    session
}
```

## Fixes

You can't allocate in a static declaration, so `Vec::with_capacity` is off limits. I've used `Vec::new`.

`Vec::append` should be `Vec::push`. If you're coming from Python, `list.append` is equivalent to `Vec::push`, while `list.extend` is like `Vec::append` or `Vec::extend`.

If you used a `static mut`, then it would make `create_session` unsafe and very easy to misuse. I've added a mutex so that it doesn't need mutability, which makes everything here safe.

You could make a `Vec<Session<dyn Application>>` or similar, but then you would not be able to return anything containing `T` from `create_session`. I've kept the `Session<T>` return and added a new trait, `SessionApplication`. This also made the `Box` inside `Session` unnecessary, so I've removed it.

## Notes

This uses `Box::leak`, which leaks memory. If you never remove items from the `Vec`, then this doesn't matter, since that memory would be in use forever anyway, but if you do remove items, you will need a lot of machinery to reclaim that memory soundly.

`Box::leak` is the only reasonable way to put the session in the static while at the same time returning it. You can't give the static ownership since it will move the items when the `Vec` reallocates, and you can't return ownership since that would be freed while references to it still exist in the `Vec`.

I would recommend not using statics or trait objects (`dyn`) for someone new to rust. Instead, put your state in a struct and use enums respectively.